# How to enqueue styles for one specific page template

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a page template which is acting as a 'Landing Page' and doesn't need specific styles from other areas of the website.

I've managed to remove the unwanted styles and add the new styles by targeting the page ID but I need it to only happen when it's a particular page template. I can't seem to get it to work when doing a check against the page template via the `is_page_template()` function.

**In functions.php:**

```php
if ( !function_exists('scripts_and_css') ) {
    function scripts_and_css() {
        if(is_page(79806))
        {
            wp_enqueue_style('landingpage', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/landing__page.css', '', null);
            wp_enqueue_script('landingpage', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/landing-page.js', null);
            wp_dequeue_style( 'layout', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/layout.css', '', null );
        }
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts_and_css');
```

If I then change this to use the template name, it completely fails and doesn't load or remove any of the scripts or stylesheets.

**My page template filename called page-landing-page.php:**

```php
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Landing Page
 * The template for displaying the content for the landing pages.
?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>

// Got all my content loading in here.

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

**Here's an example of what I've tried up to now in the functions.php fle:**

```
if(is_page_template('Landing Page'))
{
    // Enqueue / Dequeue scripts / styles
}

--

if(is_page_template('page-landing-page.php')) // This is the name of my page template
{
    // Enqueue / Dequeue scripts / styles
}

--

if(is_page_template('landing-page.php')) // This is the name of my page template
{
    // Enqueue / Dequeue scripts / styles
}

--

if(is_page_template('landing-page')) // This is the name of my page template
{
    // Enqueue / Dequeue scripts / styles
}
```

Just cannot seem to get it to work. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Is the `landing-page` template file located in a folder?

Comment: @GulJamalZim Thanks for replying. It is not, it's located within the root folder of the theme. `page-landing-page.php` is the full name of the file and my slug of the page is `landing-page`.

Comment: This isn't working for you `is_page_template('page-landing-page.php')`? Strange.

Comment: @GulJamalZim Very strange indeed. I've tripple checked all variations of this function and crawled through the WP docs and it just doesn't want to work unless I'm specifically giving it a Page ID. Page ID isn't a solution though as there's going to be multiple landing pages over time and would need to add the IDs manually which would require QA/CAB unfortunately.

Comment: Very strange! I even tested your code with the condition in my local server. And it worked fine. Yeah, Page ID isn't a good solution.

Comment: @GulJamalZim Am I right in thinking that this should work regardless of if the page has a template set via the WP Admin? By me making the template the slug name of the page, it should automatically kick in, right?

Comment: It is best to target the physical file name, like Gul said i.e. `page-landing-page.php` - can you show us how you enqueue the other styles which applies to all the pages?

Comment: @Matt You select the page template from the Template dropdown. https://imgur.com/seputNj. Are you not selecting the template from the dropdown?

Comment: So I enqueue all other styles inside the `scripts_and_css` function: `wp_enqueue_style( 'layout', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/layout.css', '', null );`.  When I select the template via Edit Page and save, the template shows up - but I don't want people selecting the template, I should be able to create a template and link it up directly via the slug in the file name. Am I thinking about this correctly, or do people have to physically select the page template when creating/editing the page?

Comment: I believe you need to include the path as well. 

is_page_template(path/your-template.php);

Comment: That all won't help. Explanation below.

Answer (score 2):

This one works perfectly.

```
      function my_enqueue_stuff() {

 // "page-templates/about.php" is the path of the template file. If your template file is in Theme's root folder, then use it as "about.php".

        if(is_page_template( 'page-templates/about.php' ))
        {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'lightgallery-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lightgallery-all.min.js');
            wp_enqueue_script('raventours-picturefill', "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/picturefill/2.3.1/picturefill.min.js", true, null);
        }
        }
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_stuff' );
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, if you do not select the page template from the Template Dropdown on the edit page, `is_page_template('template-name.php')` doesn't seem to work.

I have found a *kind-of-a-hacked* solution to your problem. It seems to be working for both of the cases. Either you select the page template from the dropdown or the template gets selected by the page-slug.

```
if( basename( get_page_template() ) == 'page-price-watch.php' ) 
{
    // Enqueue / Dequeue scripts / styles
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"is_page_template" works by checking the post meta. If the template is automatically pulled, for example because it's called home.php, the template being used is not filled into the meta. Meta is only filled when actively selecting the template for a page in the editor.

These always work and do not rely on the meta:

```
function your_enqueue_styles() {

    if (is_front_page()) {
        //works
    }

    if (is_page( array('pageslug1', 'pageslug2'))) {
        //works
    }

    global $template;
    if (basename($template) === 'template-name.php') {
        //works
    }

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_enqueue_styles' );
```

Try something like this to display the currently used page template at the bottom of the page when viewed as an admin, makes it easier to troubleshoot:

```
// Page template finder
function show_template() {
    if( is_super_admin() ){
        global $template;
        $output = '<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100%; text-align: center; z-index: 100; background-color: white; color: black;">';
        ob_start();
        print_r($template);
        $output .= ob_get_clean().'</div>';
        echo $output;
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'show_template');
```